Unit root stationarity and modelling AR(p) process
I'm reading through Introduction to Econometrics by Gary Koop. I'm a little confused on the process for modelling AR(p) processes. Hopefully someone can help clarify things for me. Let me set out my understanding and the point that I get a bit lost on.
Let's suppose that we have an AR(p) processes:
$$ Y_t = \alpha +\rho_1 Y_{t-1} + \ldots +\rho_p Y_{t-p}+\varepsilon_t \tag{1}.$$
Then we can consider the first difference of this as:
$$\Delta Y_t = \alpha + \theta Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1\Delta Y_{t-1} + \ldots + \gamma_{p-1}\Delta Y_{t-p+1} + \varepsilon_t \tag{2}$$
where $\theta = \rho_1+\dots +\rho_{p} - 1$.
If we have a set of data then we can fit $(2)$ to the data using OLS, selecting lags and parameters using sequential t-tests or likelihood function (e.g. BIC).
Once we've done that we then need to use the Dickey-Fuller test on the parameter $\theta$ with the null hypothesis $H_0\colon\ \theta = 0$. If we find no evidence to reject the null then this implies that our original model $(1)$ had a unit root. In model $(2)$ we'll have $\theta = 0$ and $\Delta Y_t$ will be stationary as we know the first difference of an AR(p) model with a unit root is stationary.
However, I'm a bit lost on what we do if we reject the null hypothesis that $\theta = 0$. In this case we can conclude that the original series does not have a unit root. Can we then do ahead and model that directly using OLS? Do we have to further assume it's not an explosive processes? Unless I'm missing something this doesn't seem covered in the textbook.

If the $Y_t$ process doesn't not have a unit root, then it's stationary as is and you can go back to the original AR(p) ( undifferenced ) and estimate it. It's possible that I'm not understanding your question.

If you find no evidence to reject the null, it means that data is consistent with having a unit root. It does not mean there is a unit root. And yes, you could reject it and have an explosive root. A better null hypothesis might have been $\theta\ge 0$
